# how to set up random number generation without remainder?

Tags: c#, random

how can I set my generator random number for division to list only numbers which, when divided, had no remainder? I need only single digit number.

I tried:

```
 Random druhy = new Random();
            Random prvni = new Random();
            
            int maxprvni = 10;
            int maxdruhy = 10;
            
            int prvnic = prvni.Next(1, maxprvni);
            int druhyc = druhy.Next(2, maxdruhy);
...
if (znamenko.Text == "/")
            {
                int zbytek = (prvnic % druhyc);
                if (zbytek == 0)
                {
                    int total = (prvnic / druhyc);
                    prvnit.Text = prvnic.ToString();
                    druhyt.Text = druhyc.ToString();
                    vysledek.Text = total.ToString();
                }

            }
```

this will not write any number to my calculator because it has a numeric remainder.

What I could write in ELSE to generate another number, and so on until the number was completely?

Comment: If you only want to generate numbers that have no remainder when divided, why don't you just generate a smaller set of numbers and multiply by `druhyc`. That seems like a pretty good way to guarantee it.

Comment: If the number must be divisible by `druhyc` then all you need to do is to generate a random number  for `druhyc` and then generate another random number and multiply it by `druhyc` and assign the result to `prvnic`

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes it would work, but i only need a single digit number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than generating a random number to divide, you could generate a random multiple of the divisor.

```
// Generate a random divisor, which could be anything except 0
int druhyc = druhy.Next(2, maxdruhy);

// Generate a random multiple of `druhyc`
// Ensure that it does not exceed maxprvni
int prvnic = druhyc * prvni.Next(1, maxprvni / druhyc);

// The division now has no remainder:
int total = (prvnic / druhyc);
```

By dividing `maxprvni / druhyc`, it ensures that the random number generated will not exceed `maxprvni` when multiplied by `druhyc`.

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HSKHF5)

Comment: yes that´s right but I need only single digit number

Comment: @memberstack Which number needs to be a single digit? `total`?

Comment: `prvnic` and `druhyc`, but if I set the max for circulation 4 then it should work even if the numbers will be simple enough for addition and subtraction

Comment: @memberstack But `prvnic` and `druhyc` will both be single digit because you have set the (exclusive) max number to be 10.

Comment: actually it's not true when I give that the second number must be single digits but then I multiply it with it so the first number definitely doesn't have to be single digits

Comment: @memberstack In that case simply increase `maxprvni`, or remove it entirely and do `int prvnic = druhyc * prvni.Next(1);`